# ngx-datatable Configurable Paging Parameter

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, paging, ngx-datatable

I am building a datatable with ngx-datatable and activated Paging with [limit]="10" for example. This works fine. However, I want to make the Entries per Page configurable through the Visitor.

So I added a variable to the controller:

`pageSize: number = 10; // defaults to 10`

Moreover I created an Item Component (is an own component of mine)

```html
<form-item
    name="pageSize"
    [(value)]="pageSize"
    (change)="table.recalculate()"
></form-item>

<ngx-datatable
      #table ...
```

which creates a:

```html
<input type="text" name="pageSize" [ngModel]="value">
```

Now, this does not work as intended. The initial value sets to 10. When I change it, the onchange callback has a mysterious delay?!. It does not react the same every time. The table.recalculate() gets fired correctly, but if I switch to the next page, the additional data gets appended to the table instead of replacing the data from the previous page.

Can someone help me, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `ngModelChange` instead of `change`

```html
<form-item
    name="pageSize"
    [value]="pageSize"
    (ngModelChange)="table.recalculate()"
></form-item>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but this does not work. ngModelChange does nothing at the moment. I guess the problem is, that I pass the [(value)] as two way binding into the <form-item> and inside form-item, I set the ngModel with <input [ngModel]="value" ... >. Only this way, the two way binding works. I will try to put the input directly into table component

Comment: sorry a typo it should be `[value]`

Comment: still, nothing happens.